# Allow ssh access to git pull on remote machine

Tags: ssh, authentication, git, public-key

We have a server with some of our git repositories on and I would like to be able to clone one to our webserver (which runs debian). I ran `ssh-keygen` on the webserver and copied the public key into `authorized_keys` on the gitserver and so now I can successfully ssh to the gitserver from the webserver:

```
ssh -T user@gitserver.com
```

And it will log me in. However, if I call git clone on the webserver:

```
sudo git clone user@gitserver.com:/dir/repo.git
```

I get this response:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I read that I should allow `ForwardAgent` in /etc/ssh_config on my local machine (running Max OS X), which I've done but didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're *not* calling `git clone`; **you're calling `sudo`** which switches to a completely different Unix account (root) and *only then* calls `git clone`.

The result, as you'd also notice with `sudo ssh -v ...`, is that `ssh` is looking for private keys in directories belonging to root, not you. Since `sudo` cleans the environment by default, `ssh` cannot use your SSH agent either, as the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable gets removed.

As you have agent forwarding enabled, try `sudo -E ssh ...` to make it preserve all environment variables.

Comment: Ah very true. Doh!

Comment: I've just shut down the test servers, but I will try that later tonight. Thanks